# Is there a fix for this Expression to get the key value pairs right

Tags: json, bash, eval, jq

I have this python script which prints this output in raw string format.

```
{"A":"ab3241c","B":"d12e31234f","c":"[g$x>Q)M&.N+v8"}
```

I am using jq to set the values of A,B and c

Something like this

```
expression='. | to_entries | .[] | .key + "=\"" + .value + "\""'
eval "$(python script.py | jq -r "$expression")"
```

This works fine A and B. And when I do something like

```
echo $A
ab3241c
```

But the problem is with c where i get the output as

```
[g\u003eQ)M\u0026.N+v8
```

so $x> and & are getting converted to unicode.
Can I fix the expression to avoid this?

I fixed it using
expression as

```
expression='to_entries | map("\(.key)=\(.value | @sh)") | .[]'
```

Comment: Why are you using `eval`?

Comment: `c="$(jq -r '.c' file)"; echo "$c"`?

Comment: I don't see how your command could possibly be working. When you eval `$expression`, the `|` will be treated as shell pipelines, not `jq` operators.

Comment: Did you mean to use `$(python script.py | jq -r "$expression")`?

Comment: Yes. sorry fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Using `eval` here is like shooting yourself in the foot.

Why not just pipe the output of your python command to the jq command?

Consider:

```
function mypython {
  cat <<"EOF"
{"A":"ab3241c","B":"d12e31234f","c":"[g$x>Q)M&.N+v8"}
EOF
}

expression='to_entries[] | .key + "=\"" + .value + "\""'

mypython | jq -r "$expression"
```

Note that using `expression` here seems pointless as well.  In general, it would be better either to "inline" it, or put it in a file and use jq's -f command-line option.

(Notice also that the first "." in your `expression` is not needed.)

Comment: I cant write it to a file. I added the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must use `eval`, then consider:

```
function mypython {
  cat <<"EOF"
{"A":"ab3241c","B":"d12e31234f","c":"[g$x>Q)M&.N+v8"}
EOF
}

expression='to_entries[] | .key + \"=\\\"\" + .value + \"\\\"\"'

eval "mypython | jq -r \"$expression\""
```

#### Output

```
A="ab3241c"
B="d12e31234f"
c="[g$x>Q)M&.N+v8"
```